# Does Google Cloud Spanner support 'struct' type?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Seems that spanner support struct type.
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-types#struct-type

However, DDL didn't mention how to use.
https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-definition-language#data_types

It's really confuse me, or I got misunderstood with the documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Cloud Spanner doesn't support Struct as a column type. It only supports Arrays as column types, but it does return data from queries in Structs so it's a data return type.